# Malkus Lorenz water wheel

Tags: non-linear-systems, bifurcation

I have read a paper by Leslie E. Matson named "The Malkus-Lorenz water wheel revisited" published in the American Journal of Physics in 2007. There the author has discussed about the behavior of the Malkus Lorenz water wheel and how the bifurcations are exhibited in the system. I was wondering whether there is a way of mathematically calculating the different bifurcation values or is it to be determined experimentally?

Comment: Hi Astro, welcome to Physics SE. Doesn't the paper you mention show the exact calculations you're asking about? In Sec. IIIa, Eq.(27), for instance, are explicit calculations of the pitchfork bifurcation points.

Comment: That's only for the pitchfork bifurcation, but for the other bifurcation there is no explicit calculations mentioned.

Comment: What about Eq.(28) for the Hopf bifurcation (referenced from a book)? Are you interested in a particular bifurcation or even in this system in particular? There are a number of methods for finding bifurcation points and if for a given system we can't identify them analytically, then, yes, we can resort to experiments, numerical or otherwise.